# Copy ALT and Paste it (Replace All) in Meta in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver, meta-tags

I have a website in Dreamweaver with thousands of HTML files and never added a meta tag/description but added the descriptions in image ALT. The HTML files are like original sized images from photo gallery thumb.

So is it possible to use "Find and Replace" using "Search: Specific Tag" or any option in Dreamweaver to copy-paste ALT content to Meta (description) content ?

I added `<meta name="description" content="replace-here">` in all html files (using template) to replace the content using Find/Replace but now I am confused because I need to move whats in ALT to meta content, not just find and replace. :/ I am not the brightest bulb.

Is this possible in anyway?

Thank you all..